# Android KSOAP2 error to get value

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, web-services

I have error to get value from web service. I try alltime but not success. I did webservice using with WCF, Entity framework. this server Works good. But I want to connect and get value from Android phone.

My Android code :

> ```
> private final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
> private final String SOAPACTION="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetValues";
> private final String METHODNAME="GetTreatmentValues";
>
> private final String URL="http://localhost:49674/Service.svc";
> ```
>
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>                     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.menu);
>   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
> @Override
>   public void onClick(View v) {
>
> ```
>           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHODNAME);
>           request.addProperty("value",1);
>
>           SoapSerializationEnvelope sp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
>           sp.dotNet=true;
>           sp.setOutputSoapObject(request);
>
>           HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
>           aht.debug = true;
>           text2.setText(aht.toString());
>           //AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
>           try {
>               aht.call(SOAPACTION,sp);  //I have ERROR! no work.
>               //SoapPrimitive resultstring = (SoapPrimitive)sp.getResponse();
>               text1.setText("test");
>               //text2.setText(resultstring.toString());
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>               // TODO: handle exception
>               text2.setText("hata!");
>           }           
>                   }       
>              });
> ```

I get error aht.call(SOAPACTION,sp);
text1 never sets "test" What should I do. I don't know what I miss. thanks. (using  Ksoap2.4)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Example, or check your code with this code
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

Hope you will get solution.

Answer (score 0):

I put my webservice into ISS. my link is http:// localhost:90/Service.svc?wsdl
in this page, I see xml code

```
 -<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" type="tns:IService">
   <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    wsdl:operation name="GetTreatmentValues">

     <soap:operation style="document"
     soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetTreatmentValues"/>


     -<wsdl:input>

     <soap:body use="literal"/>

     </wsdl:input>

     -<wsdl:output>

     <soap:body use="literal"/>

     </wsdl:output>

     </wsdl:operation>
```

I write this code into Android app

```
private final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/"; 
private final String SOAPACTION="http://tempuri.org/GetTreatmentValues"; 
private final String METHODNAME="GetTreatmentValues"; 


private final String URL="http://localhost:90/Service.svc?singleWsdl";
```

but I allways get error in here :( :(

```
try {
              aht.call(SOAPACTION,sp);  //I have ERROR! no work.
              //SoapPrimitive resultstring = (SoapPrimitive)sp.getResponse();
              text1.setText("test");
              //text2.setText(resultstring.toString());
          } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              text2.setText("hata!");
          }
```

Comment: also I can't connect browser in emulator. it can be problem ?